# JavaScript / node.js getting data out of model

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I am 100% sure there must be some simple answer but today I suck at googling. Question within the code.

```
async.waterfall([
  function(callback){
    callback(null, 'some value..');
  }
  ],
  function (err, result) {
    // how do I get result outside of this block?
   }
);
```

If I set a variable outside this block and try to assign "result" to it, it does not make out of the block because of the nature of JavaScript scopes..

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what is doing the "assigning" to `result`?  I assume you mean something within `async.waterfall`, yes?

Comment: I suspect you're trying to access the variable after the `waterfall` call, which means the problem lies precisely in the async concept. Could you elaborate on where you're accessing the outer variable?

Comment: result = 'some value..' in this case. It gets assigned via the callback.
What I am trying to do is:
set some data prior to async.waterfall,
do a chain of actions inside waterfall (all the outer variables can be accessed inside),
somehow pass the result further but I am not sure how.

Ideally I would like to set an object, work with that object inside waterfall while constantly updating its attributes AND preserve the changes when we get out of the waterfall. Workarounds accepted...

Comment: I think we need a little bit more code... are you using a specific npm package here?

Comment: Yes, async - https://github.com/caolan/async/#waterfall
I simply load the module and run the above.

Comment: Once you enter async code, you have to stay there--there's no concept of "get out of the waterfall" other than calling other functions from the waterfall's callback. You _can_, however, do modifications to objects created before entering the async code, however you still have to make sure to access it after waterfall is complete by using code or calling functions from within the callback (unless the object being modified is being treated like a global).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers. What I've done - I've switched to a module called "step" instead. It lets me do the following:

```
step = require('step');

var responseData = '{"a":1, "b":2}';

step(
  function someFunction1 () {
    // We do something here and return the result
    return '3';
  },
  function someFunction2 (err, result) {
    // We try to modify the variable that has been defined outside this block
    responseData.c = result;
  }
);

// responseData now returns {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
```

Maybe I could have done something like this with async as well - I don't know. But the above works just the way I wanted.